# UTF-8 in Domino Data Services rich text field

Tags: lotus-domino

I'm using Domino Data Service as backend for a SPA written in Angular. Rich text fields become converted to HTML as desired. But it seems like I can't alter the character set for them. Is there any way to change this to UTF-8?

In the form itself I set the content type to Notes and charset to UTF-8. The Internet site document is also set to Unicode. Maybe there is another option to change the charset.

[image]

Comment: Was this rich text field data already stored in MIME format? If that's the case, then no conversion takes place.

Comment: It's being converted successfully, so DAS prints out proper HTML for rich text fields. Unfortunately in ISO-8859-1. I just realized, in the screenshot I marked the wrong part. It should be #2, where you can see it's text/html.Even if you set the option to generate MIME and HTML for all fields, the charset stays in ISO format.

Comment: When is it being converted? Was it converted when the document was saved in the NSF file, so it is already stored in MIME format and if you look at the field in either NotesPeek or in the document properties dialog it is already showing that it is MIME with charset=iso8859-1? Or is it stored in the NSF in rich text format, so when you look at it with NotesPeek or in document properties it is not MIME, and then it is converted to MIME only when accessed by DAS?

Comment: With my approach it is not converted when the document is being saved. I also tried the respective field option, but then Ytria (not using Notes peek) also shows me that the charset is ISO-8859-1. Usually DAS converts it on the fly, anyway, but whatever I try, not to UTF-8.

Comment: If Ytria is showing you that the data is 8859-1, then the data was stored in MIME format. AFAIK, there's no reason why DAS would convert the charset in pre-existing MIME data when you read it. But are you saying that you wrote this data with DAS, too? And when you wrote the data, the charset was specified as utf-8 and DAS changed it to iso-8859-1?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "In the form itself I set the content type to Notes and charset to UTF-8."  I'm not sure what you're referring to. In Domino Designer, a rich text field defaults to Notes format; you can check a box to change it to store data as HTML/MIME, but you can't specify a charset - and changing the settings on the form will not have any affect on documents that are already saved.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. As I said, there are 2 approaches. 1st approach: Store the data as MIME in the field. (2nd tab on the field options info box) - but still the data is not stored in the desired character set (propellerhead tab on the form options info box - I can set encoding and a char set there) And 2nd approach: Let DAS convert the richtext to HTML on the fly. Tried this with the same result, it's also printed out in ISO. The Data is written directly from a client, so a client user updates the documents and in the web the rich text should be displayed as sanitized HTML content in a SPA.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the charset on the form options task is for browser rendering only, not for API access - like all the other options in that section of the dialog tab. But that's all I can really say here. I'm not sure what's going on beyond that.

Comment: That's what I've been -not- hoping. Hence the the original question if there could be another hidden switch somewhere. Thanks four your help and your time though.

Comment: it seems it will use UTF-8 if it cannot use a single characterset, say by mixing japanese and western accented characters in text. Say add a Japanese character at the end :-) But then, as what it creates is MIME, it will encode it base64.

Comment: Well, thanks, that's an interesting approach. I could reproduce this behaviour and will try to implement it in the app.